# Telerik reporting: multiple text boxes side by side, and shrinking

Tags: winforms, telerik-reporting

I would like to put multiple textboxes side by side between two labels, like this:

```
    ([=Fields.city] [=Fields.state] [=Fields.zip])
```

and have them display like this:

```
      (Punxsutawney PA 15767)
      (Concord MA 01742)
```

not like this:

```
      (Punxsutawney            PA 15767)
      (Concord                 MA 01742)
```

Is this possible? I made each textbox shrinkable but that didn't do it. I also tried docking left but that didn't work either and it also treated the string literals (the parentheses) differently than the fields bound to data.

Answer (score 0):

`CanGrow` property works only vertically. Try using `HtmlTextBox`. You can use variables or parameters there, use various styles on them etc.